# How can I take all rows with a certain criteria and generate a new sheet with the results?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I'm tracking some aircraft maintenance items. They are sorted by time remaining. I'd like to take all rows where the time remaining is less than 100 and have those listed on a separate sheet. The idea is that I would use this new sheet to generate a purchase order for the work I'm requesting to be performed by the maintenance company. Currently I'm manually taking all the information and entering into another sheet and I feel like there must be a better way?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Seems you are on `google-sheet`. You can use `FILTER()` or `QUERY()` function. Try- `FILTER(Sheet1!A2:C50000,Sheet1!B2:B50000<100)`.

Comment: @Harun24hr I took this screenshot from a Google Sheet, but I'm working in Microsoft Excel, but maybe that will still work?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I have just posted an answer below, you can refer !

Comment: you're clearly not using Excel, since the screenshot shows GoogleSheets. If you don't use Excel, please don't tag with Excel. The two are different, even though GS can open Excel files.

Comment: @teylyn mam please dont change the tag once OP has clearly mentioned they are using Excel. but they have taken screenshot from Google sheets

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Some people confuse GS and Excel all the time. It is not clear at all from the post if the OP is actually using Excel. Where do you see that?

Comment: Here in comments. _@Harun24hr I took this screenshot from a Google Sheet, but I'm working in Microsoft Excel, but maybe that will still work?_

Comment: @teylyn I've changed the screenshot to the excel file I'm using. I had it saved to my Google Drive and wasn't able to download it at the time, so I just opened it and took a screenshot. I didn't realize it would cause so much grief, I figured it was just being used for a visual reference.

Comment: Hello @AndrewFox is the formula working on your end, have you tried? please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. Instead of using blank ranges in your formula to iterate over, convert your data range into `Structured References` aka `Tables` and then use the following formula. The use of `Tables` helps in adjusting the formulas automatically when the size of the source expands or decreases. Make sure to change name of the table as per your suit.

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(Table9,Table9[Time Remaining]<100)
```

---

Even if you are using `Google Sheets` then also the said function should work, note that the only difference here is the open-ended reference which is not available in `Excel` as well as `Structured References` is a feature of `Excel`. However you can define named ranges as well to use within functions. Perhaps:

```
=FILTER(B3:D, C3:C<100)
```

---

Or use `QUERY()` function:

```
=QUERY(B3:D, "select * where Col2 < 100")
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm trying your examples, but I'm doing something wrong. I like the Query option because that feels more familiar to me, so I was trying that way. Did you put the original data into a table as well as the the extracted data?

Comment: @AndrewFox yes for `Excel` I am using the data in structured references that is `Tables` while in Google sheets you can use `QUERY()` function . From this line onwards it refers to Google sheets --> `Even if you ar` . `QUERY()` function will not work in `Excel` . The extracted data cannot be in a table because it will give youa spill error. Tables dont support spill or arrays as of now

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I think maybe a Google sheet will work best, looking at my options. So, two follow up questions using the Query option: (1) Can I make it only return the values of column 1 and column 3?, and (2) Can I make it so the value 100 is based on a cell value, so I can change it without having to change the formula?

Comment: @AndrewFox yes why not should be like this: `=QUERY(B3:D, "select Col1, Col3 where Col2 < " & F2)` let me know if that works,

Comment: This is SO great, thank you! One last question, how can I put this on a new sheet? I tried `=QUERY('Sheet1'!B3:D, ...` but it didn't work

Comment: But that worked on my end @AndrewFox `=QUERY(Sheet1!B3:D,"select Col1, Col3 where Col2 < " & F2)`

Comment: I have no idea what I did wrong before, but I tried it again and it works. Thank you SO much for your help!!

Comment: @AndrewFox glad to know it worked for you!